# Using Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, sqlite, cordova

I am using Cordova-sqlite plugin in order to  select and insert data to database embedded in an Android device. In my case I create the database from the native code and then I am trying to read some data from JavaScript source. But, I think that JavaScript is not reading from the same location as Android do.

This is my JS file :

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'db',iosDatabaseLocation: 'Library'});

    var session = this._sessionInfoService.getSessionInfo();

            db.transaction(function (tx)
            {
            var firstName = session.firstName;
            var lastName = session.lastName;
            var userId = session.id;

            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (user_id INTEGER, firstname VARCHAR, lastname VARCHAR)");
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length, i;
            console.log(len);
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
            var id =results.rows.item(i).user_id;
            console.log(results.rows.item(i).user_id );
            if(id!=userId){

                    var dialogTitle = "Another user is already registred for this device";
                    var dialogText = "Do you want to override it ";
                    WL.SimpleDialog.show(dialogTitle, dialogText, [ {
                    text : 'Override',
                    handler : function(){
                    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'db',iosDatabaseLocation: 'Library'});
                   db.transaction(function (tx)
                  {

                  tx.executeSql("UPDATE user SET user_id =?, firstname=?, lastname=?", [userId,firstName,lastName]);        
                    }
                    }
                        }, {
                    text : 'No',
                    handler : function(){
                    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'db',iosDatabaseLocation: 'Library'});
                    db.transaction(function (tx)
                     {
                    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO user (user_id,firstname, lastname) VALUES(?,?,?)", [userId,firstName,lastName]);         
                     }
                    }
                    }

                    ]);


                    }
            else{
            }
            }

        }, null);



            }


        });
    }
```

and this is my java file in native source

```
 @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {


    final SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("db",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (user_id INT, firstname VARCHAR, lastname VARCHAR);");
    Log.i("e2", "yes");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO user (user_id,firstname,lastname) VALUES(91,'ess','ess');");


            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        String query = "SELECT * FROM user";
                        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
                        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                            int userId=c.getInt(1);
                            System.out.println("userId"+userId);
                            Log.i("userId",String.valueOf(userId));

                }

            }
            catch(e){}
            }
                     });

            thread.start();
}
```

When try to create my database and my user table from JavaScript and then do  the select from java file I am facing an exception : the table user is unknown  and when I select users from the JS I always get an empty list . That's why I think that my code creates two databases with the same name but in two different locations.